# Access EBP register from C shellcode

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

I am trying to understand some assembly code so that I can work with it in C. Assume the following NASM code

```
get_entry_point:
    %define STACK_LIMIT 8
    %define return_val [ebp-4]
    %define base_ptr [ebp-8]
```

Is the `ebp` register simply accessing the parameters to a function and storing them inside `base_ptr` and `return_val`, or is it doing something else?

```
void __stdcall get_entry_point(unsigned long return_val, unsigned long base_ptr);
```

And with regards to this following code

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, STACK_LIMIT
pushad
```

What would this look like inside the prototyped C function above?

Comment: this code would look like `{`

Comment: @user253751 Haha, very funny. Possibly provide a deeper explanation of the code itself? Like I understand the code sets up the stack, but is this to say that the C compiler does this automatically and assembly its manual? But then what about the %define symbols ... it assumes the variables are already inside ebp on the stack ... how did they get there to begin with?

Comment: Negative offsets from `ebp` are usually local variables. This is what seems to be the case here too. `STACK_LIMIT` is the size of all variables. `[ebp-4]` is the address of the `return_val` variable, which takes up 4 bytes in the stack frame.

Comment: Note that your example does not initialise the two variables. Neither with parameters nor anything else. (Technically, to be exact, their stack slots will hold pseudo-random numeric values that could be left over from prior stack frames of other function calls / stack users.)

Comment: @ecm Ah, thanks so much :) That makes so much more sense!

Comment: `base_ptr` and `return_val` are *macros*.  It's a simple text replacement.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the ebp instruction

ebp is not an instruction, it's a register. It's the assembly equivalent of a variable.

`%define return_val [ebp-4]` is also not an instruction. It just means, that wherever the code says `return_val`, the assembler will treat it as if you wrote `[ebp-4]`.

> And with regards to this following code ... What would this look like inside the prototyped C function above?

This is standard code which the compiler adds to the start of every function if it needs it.

It looks like the `{` at the start of the function, because it is automatically inserted at the start of the function.

Comment: But then how does ebp know which values to place inside the variables at position -4, -8 etc? I mean, are they like variable passed to the function or are they some global values?

Comment: @randomuser843 Negative `ebp` offsets generally refer to local variables in the function or temporary values spilled on the stack by the compiler.  `ebp` isn't sentient, it doesn't know anything.  It's just a register (the *base* or *frame pointer*) holding the start of the current stack frame in the stack.

Comment: @randomuser843 ebp has the particular value because `mov ebp, esp` is basically `ebp = esp;`. So why are the variables at *esp*-4, -8 etc? It's because the caller function put them there.

Comment: (actually these must be local variables like fuz said, because arguments would be esp+something instead of esp-something. )